# Using "or" operator with imaplib search method

Tags: python, search, imaplib

I am trying to combine search criteria with the imaplib search method. For example, below I would like to search for email that had either "oracle" or "db2" as part of the FROM. Any ideas if that is possible an if yes what the syntax. I have searched Google and even the RFC 3501 but have not found an answer to this seemingly simple question.

mail.search(None, '(since "3-July-2013" SUBJECT "error" FROM "oracle")')

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `OR` operator:

`mail.search(None, 'SINCE "3-July-2013" SUBJECT "error" (OR (FROM "oracle") (FROM "db2"))')`

This is a current (4rev2) RFC 9051 for IMAP:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9051/

Though `OR` search key was already described in the previous RFC which you mentioned :)

This is a Python 3 `imaplib` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html